# Finding all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(t)-\lambda$ is separable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $f=f(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$, $\deg(f)=n \geq 2$, be a [separable polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial), namely, $f$ has $n$ *distinct* roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

> Is it possible to find all $\mathbb{C} \ni \lambda$'s such that $g(t)_{\lambda}:=f(t)-\lambda$ is also separable?

**For example:** $f(t)=(t-1)(t+1)=t^2-1$ is separable, $g(t)_{
-1}=f(t)-(-1)=t^2-1-(-1)=t^2$ is not separable, and $g_{\lambda}$ is separable for every $\lambda \neq -1$.

(I have excluded the case $n=1$, since it is trivial: Every polynomial of degree $1$ is separable, because it has only one root).

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87344/discussion-on-question-by-user237522-finding-all-lambda-in-mathbbc-such-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by definition, if a root is not of simple order it will be a root of the derivative polynome. As such, you are looking for a constant $\lambda$ such as there is a root $x_i$ of $f'$ such as $f(x_i)-\lambda = 0 $.

$\exists x_i$ such as $f(x_i) - \lambda$ and $f'(x_i)=0$

As such you can find the desired $\lambda$. And you know they will be the only possible values.

for your example the root of the derivative is 0 hence the value you are looking for is $f(0) = -1$